# Google Chrome - "aw snap" error message using Ext JS 4.0

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have the following code in my controller. This works fine in Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox. However, I get "aw snap!. Something went wrong ..." error message in Chrome.

```
init: function () {
    this.control({
        'jobslist': {
            selectionchange: this.onJobSelect
        },
        'jobdetail button[action=create]': {
            click: this.onNewJobSelect
        },
        'jobdetail button[action=save]': {
            click: this.onJobUpdate
        },
        'jobform button[action=remove]': {
            click: this.onJobRemove
        }
    });
},

onLaunch: function () {
    var jobsStore = this.getJobsStore();
    jobsStore.load({
        callback: this.onJobsLoad,
        scope: this
    });
},

onJobUpdate: function (selection) {
    var form = Ext.getCmp('jobForm');
    var record = form.getRecord();
    var values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, after much trouble resolved this. My view was extending grid:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.PartForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
```

It should have been

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.PartForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
init: function () {
        this.control({
           , <------ here
            'jobdetail button[action=save]': {
                click: this.onJobUpdate
            }
        });
    },
```

You have a blank value in your object. This is probably breaking it.

Comment: thanks well spotted. Sorry i abbreviated my code just to try and make the question more understandable. I've update it to include the whole init()

Comment: I'd start commenting-out code until it works. Start with the inner functions.